# Initialization of Multiple Inheritance in Python

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance

I came across the following python code in which a class inherits from two parent classes. I am trying to understand the constructor of the class.

```
# wrapper.py:
#############
class EWrapper:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

...

# client.py
###########
class EClient(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapper):
        self.msg_queue = queue.Queue()
        self.wrapper = wrapper
        self.decoder = None
        self.reset()
....

# Test.py
#########
class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
```

Could someone kindly shed more light on `EClient.__init__(self, self)`? It's not clear to me the usage of two `self`s. How does python know which `self` is which?

What is the process of constructing an object of `TestApp`?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "How does python know which self is which?"? There is only one object bound to all self names. The name self works like all other variable names.

Comment: On a general note, the naming of classes implies that Wrapper should *contain* a Client, not *be* a Client. Composition may be more appropriate than inheritance here.

Answer (score 2):

In the call `EClient.__init__(self, self)` the first `self` becomes that of `EClient` in `EClient`'s `def __init__(self, wrapper):`. Next, as you may see, the second `self` gets bound to `wrapper` in that call. `TestApp` inherits `EWrapper` so it uses itself as a `wrapper` for `EClient`.

Answer (score 1):

When initializing `TestApp` you are using the `self` of the `EWrapper` and then `EClient` since that is the order defined in the class.